# Pass Dynamic Data Table to Ms sql Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a scenario where am uploading a Dynamic (*some columns vary but I had to maintain their names in a table each time a user requires it, but it is not predictable so what i check is whether the column name is maintained*) Excel document and saving the content using Linq.

Unfortunately due to the dynamic columns i can no longer use Linq and have to move it to the database side. Is there a way i can pass a table without Creating a Table type?

Comment: If it truly has to contain dynamic column names, probably XML is your best bet. Or JSON, but at least MS SQL can natively (since 2005) work with XML. I'm curious how you'd query something with potentially changing column names anyway.

Comment: Thanks let me explore more on the xml option.

Comment: This Article may help you with what you are looking for. It may not be exact for MSSQL but might still give you a guidline [Linking an Excel Document to a SQL databse](http://forums.asp.net/t/1843923.aspx?How%20to%20create%20a%20flipcart%20like%20panel%20for%20showing%20products%20in%20gridview)

Answer (score 0):

its too late to reply this post but hope its usefull for newcomers

I just came accross the same scenario where i have set of employee with there Entitlement and deduction element for salary.But, it may vary and cant be predictable.

so i decided to split the set of data into two part Fixed Columns and Random Columns

if you look at the attached image. i have 2 employee with there Entitlement(Blue Highlighted) and Deduction(Yellow Highlighted).

Here EmployeeID and Name are fixed Part so i have extracted it as First DataSet

Entitlement(Blue Highlighted) and Deduction(Yellow Highlighted) are variable columns and not predictable so i have created collection of each with cmbination of employeeid as
EmployeeId - PerkName - Amount
Where PerkName is the ColumnName and its associated Amount against EmployeeId
so finaly i have two data table and i can pass them using Table type parameter in stored procedure

[check the grahical representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVcTV.png)